# How To parse multiple objects in the same JSON request/response throw SpringMVC without creating custom DTO

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jersey

I have two model classes

```
  Class User
    {
    }

    Class UserProfile
    {
    }
```

I want to use SpringMVC and JSON to send/receive(@GET,@POST) multiple objects in the same request/response.

for example:

```
{
"userprofile" : { "id":1, name:"test1" },
"user"  : {"id": 161, "name": "x"}
}
```

Comment: Ok, you want to do that. What have you done until now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is on the classpath. Make an additional inner class in your `Controller` that resembles

```
static class UserAndProfile {
    public UserProfile userprofile;
    public User user;
}
```

and then your request mappings would resemble

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserAndProfile user()  {
    UserAndProfile userAndProfile = new UserAndProfile();
    userAndProfile.userprofile = ...
    userAndProfile.user = ...
    return userAndProfile;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object user(@RequestBody UserAndProfile userAndProfile) {
    ...
}
```

See [Mapping the response body with the @ResponseBody annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) for further details.

Comment: @Francis, do I really need to create a class for this? Is it not possible without that?